# Mac OS security command works different in different versions

Tags: macos, shell

I have a command I try to run on Version `12.5`:

```
/usr/bin/security add-trusted-cert -r trustAsRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain -p ssl -p basic -d './blabla.blabla...'
```

And it works.

Then I try the same command in version `12.3.1`
But I get the following: `SecTrustSettingsSetTrustSettings: One or more parameters passed to a function were not valid.`

But, in this version, If was to run `/usr/bin/security add-trusted-cert -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain -p ssl -p basic -d './blabla.blabla...'`  it works.

Could anyone please explain? I'd like to get a working command for all versions.

By the way, If I run: `/usr/bin/security add-trusted-cert -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain -p ssl -p basic -d './blabla.blabla...'` on version `12.5` it fails for same reason.